# Dynamically set option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I set the option value selected dynamically? I have tried the same by,

```
function editFromDB(optVal) {
    $.get("/myEnd", function(myData) {                  
        var s = $('<select id="' + optVal + '" name="selectName" ></select>');
        $(myData).each(function(iter, element){
            $('<option></option>', {
                value: elem.name, 
                text: elem.name
            }).appendTo(s); 
        });
        $("#" + optVal).val(optVal);
        // ...
```

Comment: `$("option").prop("selected", true)`

Comment: You're using `optionVal`, and using `optVal` in the function.

Comment: It was a typo.. updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add " selected : true"

```
    $('<option></option>', {
                    value:"lol2", 
                    text: "yo2",
                    selected : true
                }).appendTo($("#test"));
```

Two ways to use it :

```
$(myData).each(function(iter, element){
if (your_condition_for_selected) {
            $('<option></option>', {
                value: elem.name, 
                text: elem.name,
                selected : true
            }).appendTo(s); 
        });
} else {
 $('<option></option>', {
                value: elem.name, 
                text: elem.name
            }).appendTo(s); 
        });
}
```

Or you can do :

```
$(myData).each(function(iter, element){
if (your_condition_for_selected) {
            $('<option></option>', {
                value: elem.name, 
                text: elem.name,
                selected : your_boolean_condition
  }).appendTo(s); 
        });
}
```

Comment: yeah i just wanted see the way to seleted. I edit my answer for specific selected data

Comment: The `selected : true` helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function editFromDB(optionVal){
    $.get("/myEnd",function(myData) {                   
       var s = $('<select id="' + optVal + '" name="selectName" ></select>');
       $(myData).each(function(iter,element){
            var op = $('<option>');
            ...
            if(elem.name == optVal)
                op.attr('selected','selected');
            s.append(op);

       });
      //$("#" + optVal).val(optVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to append the `select` you've created to the DOM before you can set the `val()` on it.

Secondly you can use the jQuery object you have in the `s` variable directly, without having to hack together an `id` selector. Try this:

```
function editFromDB(optVal) {
    $.get("/myEnd", function(myData) {                  
        var $s = $('<select id="' + optVal + '" name="selectName" ></select>').appendTo('body'); // append here as needed
        $.each(myData, function(i, element){
            $('<option></option>', {
                value: elem.name, 
                text: elem.name
            }).appendTo($s); 
        });    
        $s.val(optVal);
    });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/910mtaf9/)